# Disable enter button

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, jsp-tags

I am using below code to disable enter button but it is not working . this function is called when I press enter and it enters false as well but still somehow it is not working.
Is there any other method to disable enter button then please suggest.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

function stopRKey(evt) { 
  var evt = (evt) ? evt : ((event) ? event : null); 
  var node = (evt.target) ? evt.target : ((evt.srcElement) ? evt.srcElement : null); 
  if (evt.keyCode == 13)  {return false;} 
} 

document.onkeypress = stopRKey; 

</script>
```

here is my jsp code . when I presss enter it clicks on Get Next Work Item , i.e. first div tag of table.

```
<table border="0"  cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="95%" class="DataTable">
            <tr>
              <td width="23%" >
                <div align="right">
                  <a Href=""  OnMouseOut="isimgact( 'btNextWorkItem',0)" OnMouseOver="isimgact( 'btNextWorkItem',1)" onclick ="return fnNextItem( document.template);">
                    <img src="<%=PAGEBUTTON%>/GetNxtWorkItm.gif" name= "btNextWorkItem" alt="Get Next Work Item" tabindex="10" width="165" height="25" style="CURSOR: hand" border="0" ondrop="fnDrop()" ondragover="fnOverDrag()">
                  </a>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td width="2%">
              </td>
              <td width="23%" >
                <div align="Right">
                  <a Href=""  OnMouseOut="isimgact( 'btTransToList',0)" OnMouseOver="isimgact( 'btTransToList',1)"  onclick ="return fnSubmitWorkList( document.template,'<%=workList.getNoOfChkBoxes()%>','transferTL','PWL','WorkList');" >
                    <img src="<%=PAGEBUTTON%>/TnfToTeamLst.gif" name= "btTransToList" alt="Transfer To Team List" tabindex="10" width="165" height="25" style="CURSOR: hand" border="0" ondrop="fnDrop()" ondragover="fnOverDrag()">
                  </a>
                </div>
              </td>

              <td width="2%"></td>
              <td width="23%" >
                <div align="Center">
                  <a Href=""  OnMouseOut="isimgact( 'btTnfToSite',0)" OnMouseOver="isimgact( 'btTnfToSite',1)" onclick ="return fnWorkList( document.template,'<%=workList.getNoOfChkBoxes()%>','transferTS','PWL','WorkItemRout');">
                    <img src="<%=PAGEBUTTON%>/TnfToSite.gif" name= "btTnfToSite" alt="Transfer To Site" tabindex="10" width="165" height="25" style="CURSOR: hand" border="0"  ondrop="fnDrop()" ondragover="fnOverDrag()">
                  </a>
                </div>
              </td>

      <td width="2%">
              </td>

              <% if (userInfo.getRegion().equals(WebKeys.SHARED_SERVICES_REGION))
              {%>
              <td width="25%" >
              </td>
              <% }
              else
              {
              %>
             <!-- END Add INFOSYS 29-MAR-2006: REQ P6138b Disabling Imaging Worklist June 2006 release -->
              <td width="25%" >
                <div align="right">
                  <a Href=""  OnMouseOut="isimgact( 'btNextImagingWorkItem',0)" OnMouseOver="isimgact( 'btNextImagingWorkItem',1)" onclick ="return fnNextImagingItem( document.template);">
                    <img src="<%=PAGEBUTTON%>/GetImagingItem.gif" name= "btNextImagingWorkItem" alt="Get Imaging Item" tabindex="10" width="165" height="25" style="CURSOR: hand" border="0" ondrop="fnDrop()" ondragover="fnOverDrag()">
                  </a>
                </div>
              </td>
<%}%>
            </tr>
          </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$(document.body).on("keydown", function(e) {
    if ( e.keyCode === 13 ) {
    return false;
  };
});
```

Comment: Thanks sergii but I want Javascript code and not jquery.

Comment: No probs. Try: 

document.body.addEventListener("keydown", disableEnterBtn, false);

function disableEnterBtn(e) {
  if ( e.keyCode === 13 ) {
    alert("Works");
    e.preventDefault();
  };
};

Comment: Same problem , function is called but it still clicks button.

Comment: just a thought, make sure you dont have any other key event specific to that element.

Comment: ` <a Href=""  OnMouseOut="isimgact( 'btNextWorkItem',0)" OnMouseOver="isimgact( 'btNextWorkItem',1)" onclick ="return fnNextItem( document.template);">
                    <img src="<%=PAGEBUTTON%>/GetNxtWorkItm.gif" name= "btNextWorkItem" alt="Get Next Work Item" tabindex="10" width="165" height="25" style="CURSOR: hand" border="0" ondrop="fnDrop()" ondragover="fnOverDrag()">`
                  It clicks this line , I do not feel any click event is there . Do you think Is there any click present ? @VNP